# Unicode string in C#

Tags: c#, unicode-string

I remember using Unicode string in C++ such as this:

```
std::wstring str = _T("a string here");
```

What is the equivalent in C#?

Answer (score 9):

The equivalent in C# is the `String` class.

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):

> (A String) Represents text as a series of Unicode characters.
>
> [...] Each code point is encoded using UTF-16 encoding

So, if you do `string str = "a string here";`, you have a Unicode string.

Answer (score 0):

Use [System.Text.UnicodeEncoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.unicodeencoding.aspx) class. This handles UTF-16 encoding of Unicode characters.